# Apache_beam--python --error: the following arguments are required: --output-path

Tags: python, pipeline, apache-beam

****When run my code in python or colaborator the following error, I intall all libraries from apache beam, somebody gives in one moment this error or knows about it..****

usage: aaa_users_py.py [-h] [--runner RUNNER] [--streaming] [--resource_hint RESOURCE_HINTS] [--beam_services BEAM_SERVICES]
[--type_check_strictness {ALL_REQUIRED,DEFAULT_TO_ANY}] [--type_check_additional TYPE_CHECK_ADDITIONAL]
[--no_pipeline_type_check] [--runtime_type_check] [--performance_runtime_type_check]
[--allow_non_deterministic_key_coders] [--allow_unsafe_triggers]
[--no_direct_runner_use_stacked_bundle] [--direct_runner_bundle_repeat DIRECT_RUNNER_BUNDLE_REPEAT]
[--direct_num_workers DIRECT_NUM_WORKERS]
[--direct_running_mode {in_memory,multi_threading,multi_processing}]
[--dataflow_endpoint DATAFLOW_ENDPOINT] [--project PROJECT] [--job_name JOB_NAME]
[--staging_location STAGING_LOCATION] [--temp_location TEMP_LOCATION] [--region REGION]
[--service_account_email SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL] [--no_auth] [--template_location TEMPLATE_LOCATION]
[--label LABELS] [--update] [--transform_name_mapping TRANSFORM_NAME_MAPPING]
[--enable_streaming_engine] [--dataflow_kms_key DATAFLOW_KMS_KEY]
[--create_from_snapshot CREATE_FROM_SNAPSHOT] [--flexrs_goal {COST_OPTIMIZED,SPEED_OPTIMIZED}]
[--dataflow_service_option DATAFLOW_SERVICE_OPTIONS] [--enable_hot_key_logging]
[--enable_artifact_caching] [--impersonate_service_account IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
[--hdfs_host HDFS_HOST] [--hdfs_port HDFS_PORT] [--hdfs_user HDFS_USER] [--hdfs_full_urls]
[--num_workers NUM_WORKERS] [--max_num_workers MAX_NUM_WORKERS]
[--autoscaling_algorithm {NONE,THROUGHPUT_BASED}] [--worker_machine_type MACHINE_TYPE]
[--disk_size_gb DISK_SIZE_GB] [--worker_disk_type DISK_TYPE] [--worker_region WORKER_REGION]
[--worker_zone WORKER_ZONE] [--zone ZONE] [--network NETWORK] [--subnetwork SUBNETWORK]
[--worker_harness_container_image WORKER_HARNESS_CONTAINER_IMAGE]
[--sdk_container_image SDK_CONTAINER_IMAGE]
[--sdk_harness_container_image_overrides SDK_HARNESS_CONTAINER_IMAGE_OVERRIDES] [--use_public_ips]
[--no_use_public_ips] [--min_cpu_platform MIN_CPU_PLATFORM] [--dataflow_worker_jar DATAFLOW_WORKER_JAR]
[--dataflow_job_file DATAFLOW_JOB_FILE] [--experiment EXPERIMENTS]
[--number_of_worker_harness_threads NUMBER_OF_WORKER_HARNESS_THREADS] [--profile_cpu]
[--profile_memory] [--profile_location PROFILE_LOCATION] [--profile_sample_rate PROFILE_SAMPLE_RATE]
[--requirements_file REQUIREMENTS_FILE] [--requirements_cache REQUIREMENTS_CACHE]
[--requirements_cache_only_sources] [--setup_file SETUP_FILE] [--beam_plugin BEAM_PLUGINS]
[--pickle_library {cloudpickle,default,dill}] [--save_main_session] [--sdk_location SDK_LOCATION]
[--extra_package EXTRA_PACKAGES] [--prebuild_sdk_container_engine PREBUILD_SDK_CONTAINER_ENGINE]
[--prebuild_sdk_container_base_image PREBUILD_SDK_CONTAINER_BASE_IMAGE]
[--cloud_build_machine_type CLOUD_BUILD_MACHINE_TYPE]
[--docker_registry_push_url DOCKER_REGISTRY_PUSH_URL] [--job_endpoint JOB_ENDPOINT]
[--artifact_endpoint ARTIFACT_ENDPOINT] [--job_server_timeout JOB_SERVER_TIMEOUT]
[--environment_type ENVIRONMENT_TYPE] [--environment_config ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG]
[--environment_option ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS] [--sdk_worker_parallelism SDK_WORKER_PARALLELISM]
[--environment_cache_millis ENVIRONMENT_CACHE_MILLIS] [--output_executable_path OUTPUT_EXECUTABLE_PATH]
[--artifacts_dir ARTIFACTS_DIR] [--job_port JOB_PORT] [--artifact_port ARTIFACT_PORT]
[--expansion_port EXPANSION_PORT] [--job_server_java_launcher JOB_SERVER_JAVA_LAUNCHER]
[--job_server_jvm_properties JOB_SERVER_JVM_PROPERTIES] [--flink_master FLINK_MASTER]
[--flink_version {1.12,1.13,1.14}] [--flink_job_server_jar FLINK_JOB_SERVER_JAR]
[--flink_submit_uber_jar] [--spark_master_url SPARK_MASTER_URL]
[--spark_job_server_jar SPARK_JOB_SERVER_JAR] [--spark_submit_uber_jar]
[--spark_rest_url SPARK_REST_URL] [--spark_version {2,3}] [--on_success_matcher ON_SUCCESS_MATCHER]
[--dry_run DRY_RUN] [--wait_until_finish_duration WAIT_UNTIL_FINISH_DURATION]
[--pubsub_root_url PUBSUBROOTURL] [--s3_access_key_id S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID]
[--s3_secret_access_key S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY] [--s3_session_token S3_SESSION_TOKEN]
[--s3_endpoint_url S3_ENDPOINT_URL] [--s3_region_name S3_REGION_NAME] [--s3_api_version S3_API_VERSION]
[--s3_verify S3_VERIFY] [--s3_disable_ssl] [--input-file INPUT_FILE] --output-path OUTPUT_PATH
aaa_users_py.py: error: the following arguments are required: --output-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that the pipeline built in this Python script has a required customized pipeline option that includes a field named --output-path. Think it as a "template" to spawn jobs by ETL data from the --input-path to the --output-path, you have to tell the pipeline where to read and write before submitting it as a job.